# jQuery Repeat Element with A Following Number

Tags: jquery

How do I use less code here? I do not want to repeating the same steps for each element.

```
$('.slider1').stop().hover(function () {
    $('#slider_1').fadeIn('fast');
});
$('.slider1').stop().mouseleave(function () {
    $('#slider_1').hide('fast');
});

$('.slider2').stop().hover(function () {
    $('#slider_2').fadeIn('fast');
});
$('.slider2').stop().mouseleave(function () {
    $('#slider_2').hide('fast');
});

$('.slider3').stop().hover(function () {
    $('#slider_3').fadeIn('fast');
});
$('.slider3').stop().mouseleave(function () {
    $('#slider_3').hide('fast');
});
```

Comment: Are you intentionally mixing classes and IDs with the same name? Is `#slider1` nested inside of `.slider1`? There are different optimizations you could use depending on your actual HTML.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way, then -- it's too easy to potentially confuse an ID with a class when they have the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$.each([1,2,3,4], function(i, val){
    $('.slider' + val).stop().hover(function(){
          $('#slider_' + val).fadeIn('fast');
    }, 
    function(){
        $('#slider_' + val).hide('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: I think that the two events can be further combined into one; he doesn't seem to be using `.hover` correctly.

Comment: Thanks that worked. The reason I used the `.hover` like that was because I'm trying to find a way to kill the lag that happens when I scroll my mouse over the elements really quickly. Any thoughts?